# Cannot get arguments from the previous command in ZSH

Tags: command-line, zsh

There are well-known shortcuts to get arguments of the previous command in bash, like `Alt+.` or `$!`, etc. None of this is working in my zsh, I am using some zprezto modules. I was not able to find anything regarding this being changed by zprezto modules. Can it be some ZSH setting that I am missing or that I might have set and those disabled this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried starting from an empty zshrc and just enabling plugins one by one in order to find out where the culprit is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> is not to my knowledge well-known. I’m assuming this is defined by something you loaded in your bash startup. (What does it do for you?)

`$!` is the process id of the most recently started child process. I assume this is *not* what you intended to type. :)

`!$` is a (shortened) history expansion that *should* under default circumstances expand to the last argument of the previous command. zsh’s history expansion is meticulously documented [in the zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion).

History expansions usually starts with <kbd>!</kbd>, but it’s possible to change this by setting the value of `$HISTCHARS`: The first character of `$HISTCHARS` will be used as the character that initiates a history expansion. By default, `$HISTCHARS` is set to a value of `!^#`. You can check the value on your system with:

```
echo $HISTCHARS
```

If this does *not* start with `!`, then something in your zsh startup has set a different value, and standard, well-known history expansions like `!!` and `!$` will not work for you.

#### Update:

It turns out that the first paragraph I wrote above is dead wrong. I may not have known about <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>, but that may be due to the fact that I have “always” used zsh with vi mode enabled. In fact, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (and <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>, which does the same thing) are enabled in zsh’s default emacs keybindings. They’re bound to the ZLE widget `insert-last-word`, which does what you describe.

If you’re using zsh with the default emacs keybindings and <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> is not working for you, then something you’re loading in your shell startup is overriding it. You can reestablish the default keybindings with:

```
bindkey -M emacs "^[." insert-last-word \
                 "^[_" insert-last-word
```